# New car shaking

Tags: honda, steering, crv, shaking

We recently purchased a brand new Honda CRV. 3 days later while driving up in elevation at freeway speed, we experienced shaking in the steering and felt ear pressure similar to what you feel when our window is slightly down, except all wi dows were closed. Dealer is replacing the differential after balancing tires that did nothing to fix the problem. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure we'd be of much help to you, especially if the dealership is attempting to fix the issue at hand. If they are replacing the differential, I'd suggest this is most likely the issue. If it turns out not to be, they should fix whatever else may be at issue. I'm not sure we could help you diagnose it any better than what they are doing for you now. I'm sure this is all being taken care of under warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Did you recently drive through deep snow? Many times snow and or ice could accumulate  behind the rim of a tire and cause the tire to be unbalanced.

Answer (score 0):

I probably would have checked the front rotors maybe one was out of balance would cause the car to shake at high speed and also could be a differential it's possible it could have a defect bearings I probably would have replace the rotors first high speed balance the tires and have  front end realigned also balance rear tires high speed that could be an issue